# Fourier coefficients of $\;\log\log$

Tags: fourier-series, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

I was curious if there is an effective way to compute (the asymptotic of) the Fourier coefficients of 
$$
F(x)= \log\log\left(\frac{1}{\left\lvert x\right\rvert}\right) \cdot \chi\left(\left\lvert x\right\rvert\right)
$$ 
defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$ where $\chi(\cdot)$ is some smooth bump function which equals $1$ on $[-1/4,1/4]$ and $0$ outside of $[-1/2,1/2]$.

My goal is to check whether this function belongs to certain fractional Sobolev spaces, more specifically $H^s([-\pi,\pi])$ for $0 < s<1/2$.